# Add an IF statement to a SUMPRODUCT formula to Avoid Blanks

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, rounding

I have been trying to figure out how to add an IF statement to a SUMPRODUCT formula that I'm using, to round values to 2dp and then sum them if they are >=0.08. Here's the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROUND(A1:A20,2)>=0.08)*ROUND(A1:A20,2))
```

This formula works perfectly if all cells have values, however, I have some cells that have formulas in them that sometimes leave them blank. So when I use the above formula, I get the #VALUE! error. I can't seem to figure out how to add an IF statement in to the above formula,  which states that if a cell is blank, then make it equal to 0. Not sure if this is possible but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How far off is the roughly equivalent `=round(sumif(a1:a20, ">"&0.075), 2)` ?

Comment: @user7961380 user7961380 Why did you assassinate the question?

Comment: @A.S.H Why didn't you just rollback the edit?

Comment: @BJMyers for some reason I didn't find that option. Thanks for doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can force your formula to treat empty or blank cells as numeric zeros, by concatenating a leading zero to them. Try this workaround:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROUND(0&A1:A20,2)>=0.08)*ROUND(0&A1:A20,2))
```